# Inconsistent quantities in Kreuzer and Payne's Thermodynamic Room Heating equations - What am I missing?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, flow

I'm trying to get my head around thermodynamic estimates of energy needed to heat a room to a stable temperature. A naive approach would use $$Q = cm\Delta T$$ but [Kreuzer and Payne](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1119/1.3488987) rightly show that it's better to assume that the volume and pressure remain fixed, so air flows to the outside (leaving aside thermodynamic flows due to conduction and convection for now).

In that paper they derive the following formula:
[image]

And provide a result that -Q = 10MJ to raise the temperature of a 50 cubic metre room from 273 to 300 Kelvin.

I've spent the last four hours trying to replicate that result by substituting into their formula, but cannot produce the expected value. Below are the values I'm using in a Jupyter notebook so that I can easily change the values and re-run. I can't work out where I'm going wrong, because either I'm implementing the equation itself incorrectly, or am interpreting the quantities incorrectly. Can anyone shed some light?

For example, should where I have Planck's constant be replaced with some measure of enthalpy? The paper never defines h but it's used in a waveform assumption so I assume it's Planck's

Working:

```
P = 10**5 # 1 bar in Pascals
V = 4 * 5 * 2.5 # i.e. 50 cubic metres
Tf = 300 # Final temperature in Kelvin
Ti = 273 # Initial temperature in Kelvin
R = 8.31 # Gas constant
cp = 3.48*R # From the paper
Na = 6.0221415 * 10**23 # Avogadro's number
h = 6.626068*10**(-34) # Planck's constant
m = 28.96/Na/1000 # Mass of average gas particle, in kg
kb = R/Na # Boltzmann constant

Q = P*V*(math.log((Na*P/R)*((h**2)/(2*math.pi*m*kb))**(3/2))-0.5*cp*math.log(Ti*Tf))*math.log(Tf/Ti)

# Result for Q is -77,796,263...
# Expected result is around -10,000,000
```

Comment: I would be pretty surprised if $h$ was Planck's constant here. Also something very odd is going on with the units in the term in braces

Comment: I don't seem to be able to get your link to work. Are you sure the address is correct?

Comment: One sec, lemme try and fix the link

Comment: [Updated link](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1119/1.3488987). Link in main post should work now

Comment: @BySymmetry, for the terms in braces, here's my thinking so far. Do correct me of any misunderstandings:

- h is per the post, potentially should be enthalpy? If so, enthalpy at what temperature though? I used Planck's constant since it seems to be derived from the de Broglie wave equation
- Na should just be standard Avogadro's number
- m I'm unsure about, but I assumed they needed kgs per particle, so divided the molar weight in grams by Avogadro's number and 1000
- cp I have no idea how they got it, because the paragraph afterware gives 3.48 * R, but Wolframalpha gives closer to 1

Comment: I stand corrected. It does appear to be Planck's constant, somehow entering in through the density of states. I still don't understand what is going on with the units though

Comment: I think cp confuses me the most, because it doesn't seem consistent with any other definition of specific heat at constant pressure for air. Interestingly, if I use cp=3.48 instead of 3.48R, the result is roughly right, but I'm unsure why this would be the case, or whether it is just a coincidence